# Testing controller with RSpec and factory girl, can't sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, factory-bot

I just cant seem to get the sign_in to work, can anybody see where I an going wrong?

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CustomersController do

    before(:each) do
        @user = create(:user)
        sign_in @user
    end

    describe 'GET /customers' do
        it 'should be loaded successfully' do

            visit customers_path
            page.should have_content 'Customers'

        end

    end
end
```

and the factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do 

    factory :user do

        sequence(:email) { |n| "test{n}@test.com"} 
        password "testpass"
        password_confirmation { |u| u.password }
        account
    end

    factory :account do
        name "Test Account"
    end
end
```

The test fails with the content you need to sign in . That indicates the sign_in @user is not working ?

> > Failures:
>
> 1) CustomersController GET /customers should be loaded successfully
>        Failure/Error: page.should have_content 'Customers'
>          expected to find text "Customers" in "Toggle navigation Home Packages & Prices Features FREE TRIAL Contact Us Sign in Please sign
>   in × You need to sign in or sign up before continuing. Remember me
>   Sign upForgot your password? ABOUT US Our Mission Terms of Use Privacy
>   Policy DEVELOPERS Join the Team API SERVICES On-site Installation
>   LINKS OpenWeigh Home Package Info Prices Documentation Sign in TALK TO
>   US Twitter Facebook YouTube GitHub Email Us Website © 2014 OpenWeigh
>   all rights reserved. OpenWeigh is Part of the IGPython Group"
>        # ./spec/controllers/customers_controller_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in '
>
> Finished in 0.72874 seconds 1 example, 1 failure

Comment: `sign_in` is your own method or you are using Devise? If its your own then please share the code.

Comment: sign_in is the devise method `config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller`

Comment: I don't completely understand why you have a block for your password_confirmation.  Why don't you just have `password_confirmation "testpass"`?

Comment: The reason for the block is that I was sequencing the email and passwords, I have removed and tried but still the same issue?

Comment: Do you have any Devise modules running, for example 'confirmable' and that user is not yet confirmed? Or perhaps you have a 'timeoutable' and the timeout is not being set properly (or defaulting to 0)?

Comment: No None at all. Interestingly when i do it this way `@user = create(:user)
   visit login_path
   fill_in "user_email", :with => @user.email
   fill_in "password", :with => @user.password
   click_button "login"`

Answer (score 0):

Because `sign_in` is a Devise method, this answer assumes you are using Devise for user authentication.

Devise is built on Warden. By including Warden's test helper methods you can access `login_as` which serves the same purpose. Try adding the following to your spec:

```
include Warden::Test::Helper
Warden.test_mode!

before(:each) do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  login_as(@user)
end
```

Further reading within Devise's repository documentation: [How To Test with Capybara](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Test-with-Capybara).

Tested with Rails 4.1, RSpec 2.14 and Devise 3.2.